# NullPointerException in FacesCompositeELResolver how to fix or get support?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jsf-1.2

We are getting an NPE in Production, which is using apache-tomcat-8.5.28 or maybe 8.5.34 (not actually sure which but I can try to find out), with the following stack:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: while trying to invoke the method javax.el.ELResolver.getValue(javax.el.ELContext, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object) of a null object loaded from an array (which itself was loaded from field javax.el.CompositeELResolver.resolvers of an object) with an index loaded from local variable 'i'
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:62) ~[el-api.jar:3.0.FR]
    at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72) ~[jsf-impl.jar:1.2_13-b02-FCS]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169) ~[jasper-el.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:190) ~[jasper-el.jar:8.5.34]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ValueBindingValueExpressionAdapter.getValue(ValueBindingValueExpressionAdapter.java:113) ~[jsf-impl.jar:1.2_13-b02-FCS]
    ...
```

The error does not always happen, though once it does happen it seems to happen a lot for that particular server node. I've spent the last few days digging into decompiled JARs and putting breakpoints to try to understand the error.

This class is `FacesCompositeELResolver` that extends `CompositeELResolver`, and there are only 2 instances of this class ever created: one with chainType=Faces, and one with chainType=JSP. The former one (where chainType=Faces) is created as part of the first call to the FacesServlet.service() which only happens when you hit the server the first time.

The parent class, `CompositeElResolver`, is trying to call getValue which has code like this:

```
// copied from CompositeELResolver.java

public Object getValue(ELContext context, Object base, Object property) {
    context.setPropertyResolved(false);
    int sz = this.size;

    for(int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
        Object result = this.resolvers[i].getValue(context, base, property); // <----  line 62 NPE here
        if(context.isPropertyResolved()) {
            return result;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

In this case it's important to recognize that the error mentions that the array "this.resolvers[i]" contains a null element at the ith position. The following code is responsible for setting the value inside the this.resolvers array:

```
// copied from CompositeELResolver.java

public void add(ELResolver elResolver) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(elResolver);       // <---- line 47
    if(this.size >= this.resolvers.length) {
        ELResolver[] nr = new ELResolver[this.size * 2];
        System.arraycopy(this.resolvers, 0, nr, 0, this.size);
        this.resolvers = nr;
    }

    this.resolvers[this.size++] = elResolver; // <---- line 54
}
```

At face value, it looks like it would be impossible for this.resolvers array to get a null value in a array position which has index less than this.size due to line 47 validating that the value cannot be null; however, it is possible in a multi-threaded environment with 2 threads sharing the same object reference. The first part I mentioned about `FacesCompositeElResolver` being a shared object only instantiated once and shared across all threads is important.

Supposing 2 Threads called FacesServlet.service() at exactly the same time and executed the call to `add(elResolver)`, then line 54 `this.resolvers[this.size++] = elResolver;` can be called at the same time on the same `FacesCompositeELResolver` instance, that would cause `this.size++` to happen 2 times before the assignment to the array position is executed, causing a race condition.

So I put a break point at the CompositeELResolver.add function and see who calls this, and see if that code is protected with some sort of `synchronized` function which would protect this code in a multi-threaded environment.

```
javax.el.CompositeELResolver.add():54
com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeElResolver.add():60
com.sun.faces.el.ElUtils.buildFacesResolver():160
```

This might be the problem, though I have not yet reproduced the problem, I suspect the above stack is to blame.

To summarize the ElUtils.buildFacesResolver, a static function, is modifying a shared object of type FacesCompositeELResolver, and if the server is "lucky" enough to call this same stack in 2 threads at startup this would result in a `this.resolvers` array in the singleton instance containing a null object which would constantly through NullPointerException until the server is bounced - which does seem to be precisely what we're seeing.

But here's the thing none of this really belongs to the Application code being run, it seems part of the jsf-impl.jar which we're using which seems at version 1.2_13-b02-FCS according to the manifest.mf file in that jar. I'm not sure where this version comes from, or how I could modify it if I needed to.

Can someone help me to understand where I might be able to get support on these particular classes, is this something that I can control?

Any other help or clues someone can provide on this would be helpful.